# HTML Tables Cell Switching

Tags: javascript, html

I can't find out how to do this...

I have a cell in a table that I want to have stacked so that when someone types in a number in a text box an image shows up but if they type in another number, text shows up in the same cell instead of the image. I know this might involve some java-script as well. Something along the lines of this:

```
if textinbox = 1
    CellInTable = Image
    Hide xyzText

if textinbox = 2
    Hide image
    CellInTable = xyzText
```

*(pseudocode)*

The text box is in a different cell of the table and not the same cell and 90% of my JS is called from another file. Any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a litle code for you, I think that this is what you meant, as your description wasn't that clear...

**The HTML:**

```
<table style='border:grey 1px solid; background-color:silver; width:200px;' cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="number" style='width:100px' /></td>
    <td id="cell"></td>
</tr>
</table>​
```

**The Javascript** *(used jquery)*:

```
$("#number").keyup(function() {
    var img;
    switch($("#number").val()) {
        case "1":
            img = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/26/Smile.png";
            break;
        case "2": 
            img = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/72/Teeth.png";
            break;
        case "3":
            img = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5c/Angry.png";
            break;
        default:
            img = false;
            break;
    }
    if (img) {
        $("#cell").html("<img src='"+img+"' />");
    } else {
        $("#cell").html("");
    }
});
```

To see it working: http://jsfiddle.net/M8E5f/3/